# Query optimization for hive table

Tags: database, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, database-performance

We have a table which is of size 100TB and we have multiple customers using the same table (i.e every customer uses different where conditions). Now the problem statement is every time a customer tries to query the table it gets scanned from top to bottom.

This creates lot of slowness for all the queries. We cannot even partition/bucket the table basing on any business keys. Can someone provide solution or point to similar problem statements and their resolution.

you can provide your suggestions as well as alternative technologies so that we can pick the best suitable one. Thanks.

Comment: Table type? Column types? Partition keys? Average file size? HDFS replication factor vs. number of nodes available? Tez or MapReduce? Is there ANY KIND OF INFORMATION that you can provide about your setup???

Comment: The table contains device data Ex: routers,modems. 
The columns contains the Instance ID's(hostnames), location, etc. 
There are no partition keys. 
The average file size is 2.5GB. 
The replication factor is 3. 
The cluster is a 16 node cluster.
Uses Mapreduce.

Comment: Let me know if you need any other information

Comment: Table type => Text? AVRO? SequenceFile? ORC? Parquet? And what kind of compression: none? Snappy? GZip?

Comment: Table type: text.Compression: snappy

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents: experiment with an ORC table with GZip compression (default) and clever partitioning / ordering...

- every *SELECT* that uses a partition key in its *WHERE* clause will
  do "partition pruning" and thus avoid to scan everything *[OK, OK, you said you had no good candidate in your specific case, but in general it can be done so I had to mention it first]*
- then within each ORC file in scope, the min/max counters will be
  checked for "stripe pruning", limiting the I/O further

With clever partitioning & clever ordering of the data at *INSERT* time, using the most-frequent filters, the pruning can be quite efficient.

Then you can look into optimizations such as using a non-default ORC stripe size, a non-default "bytes-per-reducer" threshold, etc.

*Reference:*

1. http://fr.slideshare.net/oom65/orc-andvectorizationhadoopsummit
2. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC
3. https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/display/HADOOP/Optimizing+ORC+Files+for+Query+Performance
4. http://thinkbig.teradata.com/hadoop-performance-tuning-orc-snappy-heres-youre-missing/

One last thing: with 15 nodes for running queries and a replication factor of 3, each HDFS block is available "locally" on 3 the nodes (20%) and "remotely" in the rest (80%). A higher replication factor may reduce I/O and network bottlenecks -- at the cost of disk space, of course.